# implicit conversion in template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

In the following code I have a nonmember template function and a full specialization of it for a type `int`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
void f(const U& x, const U& y)
{
  std::cout << "generic " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}

template <>
void f(const int& x, const int& y)
{
  std::cout << "specialization int " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  f(a, a);
  f('a', 'a');

  f('a', 1); // Compiler error
  // f<int>('a', 1); // This compiles

  return 0;
}
```

Although an implicit conversion from a `char` to a `int` is available in the language, the compiler (g++ 7.3.0 and clang 6.0.1) does not compile the code, giving error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘f(char, int)’
deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const U’ (‘char’ and ‘int’)
```

While it is clear why the template deduction would not work, it is unclear to me why the compiler does not consider the implicit conversion once it has discarded the general template. For instance, if I explicitly instantiate `f` with `U=int` uncommenting the corresponding line in the code as

```
f<int>('a', 1);
```

then the code compiles and correctly gives the output

```
specialization int 1 1
generic a a
specialization int 97 1
```

If, instead, I supplement the code with an *overload* of `f` instead of a template specialization as

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename U>
void f(const U& x, const U& y)
{
  std::cout << "generic " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}

void f(const int& x, const int& y)
{
    std::cout << "overload int " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 1;
  f(a, a);
  f('a', 'a');

  f('a', 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Then the code compiles and gives the expected output

```
overload int 1 1
generic a a
overload int 97 1
```

In summary: Why implicit conversions work for an overload but not for a seemingly equivalent template specialization?

Comment: Did you read the compiler error message? It says me something like `"template parameter 'U' is ambiguous"`. So the problem is not in inability to implicitly convert from `char` to `int`, but ambiguity of the call.

Comment: From [this template argument deduction reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) (more specifically the [implicit conversion section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions)): "Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions ...: that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later."

Comment: @vahancho Sorry, the compiler I use and mention do not give the warning *ambigous*.

Comment: Another reason to prefer overload to specialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When compiler see this:

```
f('a', 1);
```

It is unable to deduce type since it has two choices:

```
f(const char &, const char &);
f(const int &, const int &);
```

Since your template has common type for both arguments.

Both choices are equally valid and there is no reasonable rule to resolve this ambiguity. So compiler has to report an error to avoid undesired behavior. Note that silent type conversion has no impact on this problem, also your specialization of template also can't help resolve this issue.

Same problem will be raised for `std::max`.

Now question is are you sure that second argument is more important and should have impact on template argument type? If yes then you can force to ignore type of first argument (disclaimer: this is unusual and unexpected so it may be a bug prone for future code mainteinrs).

```
template <typename T>
struct Identity {
    using type = T;
};
// note C++20 introduces std::type_identity

template<typename T>
void f(const typename Identity<T>::type& x, const T& y)
{
  std::cout << "generic " << x << " " << y << std::endl;
}
```

In this form first argument will not take a part in type deduction for template, since it depends on type of second argument.

Now this

```
f('a', 1);
```

will compile since second argument will lead to `T=int` and first argument type is expected to be same as for second argument. Now silent conversion can be performed.

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MUkUQRHsp5TDm63B).

Answer (score 1):

> Why implicit conversions work for an overload but not for a seemingly equivalent template specialization?

Because a template specialization is, exactly, a specialization.

So, when you have the template function and the template specialization, and you write

```
f(x, y);
```

the compiler deduce the types for `x` and `y`.

If, and only if, the deduced types are the same, consider the template function and if, and only if, the type is `int` (for both arguments), choose the specialization.

When you call

```
f<someType>(x, y);
```

you say the compiler: "ignore the type deduction and call the template function `f()` imposing `someType` as `T`".

In that case, writing

```
f<int>('a', 1);
```

the compiler choose the template specialization and convert `a` to `int`.

With a non-template function is different because it's ever available and the compiler has only to verify that all arguments are equal or convertible to the arguments of the function.