# C++: Implicit conversion when templates are explicitly instantiated

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, type-traits, explicit-instantiation

It is well known that when we want to have the declarations of templated class/functions in a header file and the their definition in a source cpp file, the must add explicit instantiation at the end of said cpp file - with the limitation that, then, our templates will only work for the explicitly defined cases.

For example, let's say we have the following header with a templated class that has an also templated member function:

```
// header classA.h

template<class T>
class ClassA
{
    /* template<class U> */
    /* friend class ClassA; */
public:
    template<typename U>
    void foo(U val);
};

extern template class ClassA<double>;
extern template void ClassA<double>::foo(double);
```

Here, `extern` tells the compiler that whenever this header is included, the compiler should not try to instantiate ClassA or its member function here - the definitions will come elsewhere.

In our case, they come from the following cpp source file:

```
// header classA.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "classA.h"


template<class T>
template<typename U>
void ClassA<T>::foo(U val)
{
    // other code that uses val goes here
    printf("foo\n");
}

template class ClassA<double>;
template void ClassA<double>::foo(double);
```

And we test the code with this main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "classA.h"

void test(double x) { printf("test\n"); }

int main()
{
    ClassA<double> a;
    float x = 1.0; // this being a float throws a linker error; it must be double
    a.foo(x);
    test(x);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code, as is, does not compile because `x` is `float`. The `ld` linker (with G++ 12.3.0) throws the link error:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVYWPa2.o: in function `main':
> main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): undefined reference to `void
> ClassA<double>::foo<float>(float)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory``
> ```

If we change `x` to be a `double`, then the program compiles as expected. That is, when `x` is `float`, the implicit conversion from float to double is not kicking in. What I don't understand is why. Surely, in general the compiler cannot unambiguously decide the type of a templated parameter. But since an explicit instantiation is being given - and just one in this simple example - I would expect the compiler to implicitly convert a float to a double when passing to `foo` - because there is no other option being explicitly instantiated as to create ambiguity.

That is, I could certainly understand the ambiguity when explicitly instantiate more cases like:

```
template class ClassA<double>;
template void ClassA<double>::foo(double);
template class ClassA<double>;
template void ClassA<double>::foo(long double);
```

So, my question is two-folded:

1. why is the implicit conversion not happening eve if there are no ambiguous cases being explicitly instantiated?
2. in examples like those, is there a way to enforce implicit conversion **at least when `T` = `U`** (i.e. perhaps based on `T`, [analogous to this answer to a similar but different case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901944/6363820))?

**EDIT:** Obviously, I need both `T` and `U` separately. Otherwise I could just drop the function template and use `T` instead of `U`.

Comment: It is `explicit instantiation` not `explicit initialization`. Also instantiation does not play a role at all in type deduction.

Comment: @JaMiT that was a typo/edit error on my part. Just corrected. Forget int, try with `ClassA<double>` and `float x` and the error will be shown. But it will compile correctly with `double x`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It’s not linking because `float` matches `U` and then it’s looking for a definition which doesn’t exist.
2. Take `T` as the function argument, so the function isn’t templated (just the class it’s a member of). Then `a.foo` will expect an `int`, which will lead `a.foo(x)` to do an implicit conversion. And then it won’t link because you only provided a `double` version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I must have `T` and `U` separately, otherwise of course I could simply drop the function template

Comment: Then depending on what you want, add an `extern template void ClassA<int>::foo(double);` and do `a.foo<double>(x)`. Or you could get fancy and provide overloads that do this conversation for you.

Comment: But those also do not relate to **implicit conversions**, do they? Also, about point 1., sure, `float` matches `U` and there is no `float` instantiation for it. But again, there is only one instantiation: for double, which float can be implicitly converted to. There is no ambiguity

Comment: There is no ambiguity: `a.foo(x)` is going to find `a.foo<float>(x)` and then fail to link. It’s that simple. The externes doesn’t affect the compiler, just the linker. If you want to add complexity, something like `template <std::convertible_to<T> U> void foo(U x) { this->foo<T>(x); }` you could.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is because `U` is deduced to be `float` and instantiation does not play a role at all in type deduction. Providing a explicit instantiation where the type is not a perfect match cannot prevent the compiler from generating an implicit instantiation where the type is a perfect match. It is not at all about overload resolution, so arguments about ambiguity simply do not apply here.
2. You can make a simple forwarding function (a specialization) using SFINAE techniques. I am using concepts here but you can use other techniques suitable for your c++ version. For those forwarding functions, you need to provide in-class definitions. Something like

```
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template<class T>
class ClassA
{
    /* template<class U> */
    /* friend class ClassA; */
public:
    template<typename U>
    void foo(U val);
    
    template<typename U>
    requires (std::assignable_from<T&, U> && !std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<U>, T>)
    void foo(U&& val){
        return foo<T>(std::forward<U>(val));
    }
};

extern template class ClassA<double>;
extern template void ClassA<double>::foo(double);
```